# Kubernetes pod crashLoopBackOff, need to remove a pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, crashloopbackoff

I have installed Prometheus using helm chart, so I got 4 deployment files listed:

- prometheus-alertmanager
- prometheus-server
- prometheus-pushgateway
- prometheus-kube-state-metrics

All pods of deployment files are running accordingly.
By mistake I restarted one deployment file using this command:

`kubectl rollout restart deployment prometheus-alertmanager`

Now a new pod is getting created and getting crashed, if I delete deployment file then previous pod also be deleted. So what can I do for that crashLoopBackOff pod?

[Screenshot of kubectl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxvwP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [delete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete) that pod with the `kubectl delete pod <pod_name>` command or attempt to delete all pod in `crashLoopBackOff` status with:

```
kubectl delete pod `kubectl get pods | awk '$3 == "CrashLoopBackOff" {print $1}'`
```

Make sure that the corresponding deployment is set to 1 replica (or any other chosen number). If you delete a pod(s) of that deployment, it will create a new one while keeping the desired replica count.

Answer (score 0):

These two pods (one running and the other crashloopbackoff) belong to different deployments, as they're suffixed by different tags, i.e: `pod1-abc-123` and `pod2-abc-456` belong to the same deployment template, however `pod1-abc-123` and `pod2-def-566` belong to different deployments.

A deployment is going to create a replicaset, make sure you delete that corresponding old replicase, `kubectl get rs | grep 99dd` and delete that one, similar to the prometheus server one.